# On partial sums of the Ramanujan sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $c_{m}(n)$ denote the $m^{th}$ [Ramanujan sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum) at $n$. What is the best known estimate for $\sum_{m=1}^{N} c_{m}(n)$?

Comment: Is $n$ fixed or do you want $n$ to also vary with $N$? For the former, you can just write $c_m(n) = \sum_{a \mid (m,n)} a \mu\left(\frac{m}{a}\right)$ and interchange the order of summation, so that $\sum_{m \leq N} c_m(n) = \sum_{a \mid n} a \sum_{m \leq \frac{N}{a}} \mu(m)$, then use the fact from the prime number theorem that $\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) = O(x \exp(-C\sqrt{\log x}))$ for some absolute constant $C > 0$.

Comment: @Peter Humphries, thanks. Indeed, I was taking $n$ to be fixed.